# Create a dictionary with twitter hashtag counts

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, twitter, web-scraping

I read in a file of tweets I downloaded from a shared drive:

```
lst = list()
with open('cwctweets.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as infile:
    txt = infile.readlines()
```

Turned it into a list of 10 dictionaries:

```
for line in txt:
    dct = dict(line)
    lst.append(dct)
```

Each dictionary has I think 15 tweets, except the first one, `lst[0]`, which has 100.

What I am trying to do is create a dictionary that contains the hashtags as keys, and the counts of the hashtags as the values.

All the dictionaries (0-9) look like this:

```
lst[0].keys()
dict_keys(['search_metadata', 'statuses'])
```

And I'm only focusing on 'statuses':

```
lst[0]['statuses'][1].keys()

dict_keys(['geo', 'entities', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'favorite_count', 'retweeted', 'id', 'place', 'source', 'text', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'favorited', 'id_str', 'lang', 'truncated', 'contributors', 'created_at', 'metadata', 'retweet_count', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'coordinates', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'user', 'in_reply_to_status_id'])
```

Here is where I find hashtags:

```
lst[0]['statuses'][1]['entities'].keys()

dict_keys(['user_mentions', 'hashtags', 'urls', 'symbols'])
```

So I can do this to print out the hashtags:

```
for a in lst:
    for b in a['statuses']:
        print(b['entities']['hashtags'])
```

And my output looks like this:

```
[{'indices': [47, 56], 'text': 'WorldCup'}, 
{'indices': [57, 63], 'text': 'CWC15'}, {'indices': 
[64, 72], 'text': 'IndvsSA'}]
[{'indices': [107, 113], 'text': 'CWC15'}, 
{'indices': [114, 122], 'text': 'NZvsENG'}, 
{'indices': [123, 134], 'text': 'Contenders'}]
...
```

But when I try this to create a dictionary with hashtags as keys and hashtag counts as values:

```
dct1 = dict()
for a in lst:
    for b in a['statuses']:
        if b['entities']['hashtags'] not in dct1:
            dct1[b] = 1
        else: 
            dct1[b] += 1
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-cc2e453c6f6d> in <module>()
      2 for a in lst:
      3     for b in a['statuses']:
----> 4         if b['entities']['hashtags'] not in dct1:
      5             dct1[b] = 1
      6         else:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Now I'm not sure why it isn't working if I can just print out the hashtags in a similar manner, any help, please?

Comment: `b` is a dict, no?  if so, what is the point of `dct1[b]`?  What key do you really want?

Comment: @StephenRauch my idea is to have a dictionary with hashtags and frequency, then convert it into a pandas data frame.

Answer (score 0):

The unhashable type error appears when a type such as a `list` type is used to access a dictionary. The reason for this is that lists cannot be used as a key for a dictionary.

The line `if b['entities']['hashtags'] not in dct1:` checks if a given key is not in a dictionary.

Print the value of `b['entities']['hashtags']`. if it has `[` and `]` surrounding it, that means it is a list.

From your code above it seems that the `hashtags` key of `b['entities']` contains a list of hashtags. According to your needs, you will need to possibly choose one of the values in `hashtags` and use that to check through each value in your other dictionary.